# Spark throwing "java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" when spark context is stopped

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently experimenting with a single node Spark cluster, running in standalone mode on Windows and running scripts written in Pyspark.

When ever a `sc.stop()` command is issued I am receiving a `java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` exception on the worker.

It appears that my tasks are completing successfully.  The console is showing a status of finished for each application and all the outputs are as expected.

The full message is as follows:

```
19/08/06 09:44:10 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /10.99.6.55:49794
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1106)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:123)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Does anyone know how I can make this message go away?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. TCP is meant to work this way.

Comment: I kind of had a feeling that this might be the case.  Unfortunately, I got a little bit burnt with an error that I didn't pick up because of the noise.  Thankfully I am only in dev at this stage!